# How can I fix this NRE when trying to read .txt file?

Tags: vb.net, text-files, nullreferenceexception

I have this code:

```
Dim TextRead As StreamReader = File.OpenText(FilePath)
Do While TextRead.Peek <> -1
    Select Case True
        Case TextRead.ReadLine.EndsWith("25m Freestyle") : lstF25.Items.Add(TextRead.ReadLine())
        Case TextRead.ReadLine.EndsWith("50m Freestyle") : lstF50.Items.Add(TextRead.ReadLine())
        Case TextRead.ReadLine.EndsWith("25m Backstroke") : lstB25.Items.Add(TextRead.ReadLine())
        Case TextRead.ReadLine.EndsWith("50m Backstroke") : lstB50.Items.Add(TextRead.ReadLine())
    End Select
Loop
TextRead.Close()
```

What it's trying to do is read the end of each line and place it into 4 different ListBoxes depending on what the end of the line says, but I'm receiving a NullReferenceExeption in the case statement.

I know that I'm not adding NULL into the listboxes because it wouldn't have caused the .EndsWith() to equal true.

Here's an example of what the textile looks like:

```
John, Smith, 70, 25m Freestyle
Alice, Smith, 73, 50m Freestyle
Bob, Smith, 71, 25m Backstroke
Charlie, Smith, 74, 50m Backstroke
David, Smith, 76, 25m Backstroke
```

Comment: You should read the current line before selecting the destination of that piece of text. You probably better read all the lines beforehand, using a `List(Of String)` as container, then assign lines of text to a Control using LINQ's `.Where(...).ToArray()` (either setting the DataSource or using the `Items.AddRange()` method). -- You should specify which UI Platform these ListBox Controls belong to.

Comment: Part of your problem is your are calling Read Line twice for each Case.  As @Jimi says, read the line once into a variable of some nature before doing any processing on it

Answer (score 0):

In select case clause you always call readline multiple times in one loop.
Correct way:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TextRead As StreamReader = File.OpenText("d:\test.txt")
    Do While TextRead.Peek <> -1
        Dim line As String = TextRead.ReadLine()
        Select Case True
            Case line.EndsWith("25m Freestyle") : lstF25.Items.Add(line)
            Case line.EndsWith("50m Freestyle") : lstF50.Items.Add(line)
            Case line.EndsWith("25m Backstroke") : lstB25.Items.Add(line)
            Case line.EndsWith("50m Backstroke") : lstB50.Items.Add(line)
        End Select
    Loop
    TextRead.Close()
End Sub
```